# Is there a common way to deploy a Django application with Windows Server ISS?

Tags: python, django, deployment, windows-server

I deployed a Django application on a Windows Server 2016 of a customer, but he wants it deployed through ISS, which as a Linux person i had no idea what it was.

So I searched for it, and how to deploy a Django application using ISS.

The best content I could find about this was on [Matt Woodward](https://www.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/23/running-a-django-application-on-windows-server-2012-with-iis/) post from years ago.

Still it didn't work as expected, and I can't find where the problem is.

specs:

django 4.2
wfastcgi 3.0
python 3.11
windows server 2016

folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

## Steps

This was my steps trying to get it working.

## Setting up dependencies

1 - Installed Python and IIS on the OS;

2 - Created virtual environment and installed project requirements + wfastcgi;

3 - Tested Django application - working fine with runserver;

## Configure FastCGI

1 - As Full path value: C:\Users\one\Documents\app\myApplication\virtualenv\Scripts\python.exe

2 - As arguments value: C:\Users\one\Documents\app\myApplication\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py

3 - For environment variables:

- DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: core.settings
- PYTHONPATH: C:\Users\one\Documents\app\myApplication\core
- WSGI_HANDLER: django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()

## Configure IIS Site

1 - As Content Directory/Physical path: C:\Users\one\Documents\app\myApplication\core

2 - For Handler Mappings:

- Request path: *
- Module: FastCgiModule
- Executable: C:\Users\one\Documents\app\myApplication\virtualenv\Scripts\python.exe|C:\Users\one\Documents\app\myApplication\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py

Now when I go to http://localhost:81

I receive this page [image: Error]

Now I don't know if there's some problem with configs or is an authentication problem, any ideas ?

Comment: A simple Django app can be hosted on IIS without much trouble, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-django-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ The decade old posts can be skipped as so much has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this settings in FastCGI

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: core.settings

WSGI_HANDLER: core.wsgi.application

PYTHONPATH: C:\Users\one\Documents\app\myApplication

Comment: Gave me this error:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.